# load responsive css in laravel 4

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-4

I understand that you can load css and script in laravel 4 using:

`{{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}`

and it will produce:

`<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/cupcakes-laravel/public/css/style.css">`

Now, how can I load my responsive css to have like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 1023px), only screen and (max-device-width : 1023px)" href="css/tablet.css" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an array with extra attributes such as media as the second parameter.

```
{{ HTML::style('css/tablet.css', array('media'=>'only screen and (max-width: 1023px), only screen and (max-device-width : 1023px)'); }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following method instead of generating the whole link using blade

```
 <link href="{{ URL::to('/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```